# Select points by polygon and update attribute field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

For each record in the pointLayer, I'm trying to see where they are located using the polygonLayer. Then, update this location information to the "SWPsubwatersheds" field from the pointLayer using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor. I don't get any errors running the code but when I open up my pointLayer table, I see incomplete updates (image at the end of this post).

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

```py
#A. libraries  
import arcpy  
import os

#B. set up work environment  
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Pathogens/SC Outfalls (ALL)/SC Outfalls (ALL).gdb" 

#C. import data and prepare for data analysis 
## outfall shp file  
ALL =  "C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Pathogens/SC Outfalls (ALL)/SC Outfalls  (ALL).gdb/Outfalls_All_XY_ExcelToTable1_XYTableToPoint"  
## waterbody shp file  
waterbody = "C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Pathogens/SC Outfalls (ALL)/SC Outfalls (ALL).gdb/Waterbodies_and_Estuaries_correctCS"

#D. Make feature class data    
pointLayer=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ALL, 'ALL_layer')  
polygonLayer=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(waterbody, 'waterbody_layer')  

#E. Select points within polygon and update attributes   
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygonLayer, "BigDisso_3"):  
    query= '"BigDisso_3"=' + "'" + row[0] +"'"  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(polygonLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", query)  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(pointLayer, "INTERSECT", polygonLayer, "", "NEW_SELECTION")  
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pointLayer,["SWPsubwatersheds"]) as cursor:  
        for row1 in cursor:  
            row1[0]=row[0]  
            cursor.updateRow(row1)
```

[image: Below is the pointLayer attribute table I get running the code. As you can see, it's incomplete]

Comment: The first rule of DA cursors is to *never* nest them. While you could kludge together code to make that work correctly with cursors, what you really want to do is a Spatial Join, and then CalculateField to move the attribute across. The alternate is to use Identity to pass the points through the polys and pick up all the attributes (the extras of which you can then drop with Delete Field). If I had to use cursors, I'd use the Polygons to find the IDs of Points within it, building a dictionary of [pointID] = PolyValue, then run a simple UpdateCursor to use PointID to set PolyValue.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest cursors I believe that you are not updating the selection each time.

```
    point_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(pointLayer, "INTERSECT", polygonLayer, "", "NEW_SELECTION") 

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(point_selection, ["SWPsubwatersheds"]) as cursor:  
        for row1 in cursor:  
            row1[0]=row[0]  
            cursor.updateRow(row1)
```

However I would do this differently with cursors to increase speed and simplify.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygonLayer, ["SHAPE@","BigDisso_3"]) as srch_cursor:
    for row in srch_cursor:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pointLayer,["SHAPE@","SWPsubwatersheds"]) as cursor:  
            for row1 in cursor:
                if row1[0].within(row[0]):
                    row1[1]=row[1]  
                    cursor.updateRow(row1)
```

Adding the "SHAPE@" generic in the field list at index 0, then using the same method for the point.
continues if not within.